# Access free text field in shopware

Tags: smarty, textfield, shopware

Hello I would like to use free text fields in my custom template, but after half day of searching how to access it in my template, I'm still not sure how :/ maybe anyone here have some experience with that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnCBZ.png)

Comment: Can you provide code snippet? Where you want to use manufacturer attributes? You can use {debug} smarty tag for check all variables in your template. In case manufacturer attributes isn't there, you should subscribe to `Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatch_Frontend_RequiredPageName` and fetch attributes manually.
If you have attributes, but don't have your one, maybe you didn't regenerate attribute proxy, try to press `Generate Entity`(you can see button on your screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

In your Template file you can access the freetextfield with `{$sArticle.yourfreetextfieldname}`.

But there are other options too. You can take a look at the [Developer Docs](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/attribute-system/#show-attributes-in-the-frontend) how to use the freetextfield's in shopware.